# Ruby : How to integrate Iluminati API Proxies to Automation ruby program

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, selenium-webdriver, proxy, reverse-proxy

**Hello, i was recently looking for a proxy provider that has rotating proxies so i found one but now i dont know how to integrate it for example opening a browser like `google.com` using selenium webdriver .
The code below was provided by the proxy provider company . How can i integrate it to open a browser and navigate to a page using their proxies ?**

```
require 'uri'
require 'net/http'
require 'net/https'

puts 'To enable your free eval account and get CUSTOMER, YOURZONE and YOURPASS, please contact 
sales@luminati.io'

uri = URI.parse('http://lumtest.com/myip.json')
proxy = Net::HTTP::Proxy('proxy', port, 'username', 'password')

req = Net::HTTP::Get.new(uri.path)

result = proxy.start(uri.host,uri.port, :use_ssl => uri.scheme == 'https') do |http|
    http.request(req)
end

puts result.body
```